# Nilpotent Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and $A, B\in M_n(\mathbb K)$ be nilpotent matrices. Suppose that $nullity(A)\cap nullity(B)\geq 1$.

Can we find a regular matrix $T$ such that the first columns of the two matrices $T^{-1}AT$ and $T^{-1}BT$ are zero?

Comment: A nullity is a number.  They don't have an intersection.  I assume you mean the dimension of the intersection of the null spaces of $A$ and $B$ is $\ge 1$.

Comment: Pick a basis of the intersection of the two kernels and complete it to a basis of the whole space; use the vectors as columns of $T$.

Comment: (Notice that the nilpotency of the matrices plays no role here.)

Answer (score 1):

The first column of $T^{-1} A T$ is $T^{-1} A T e_1$ where $e_1 = (1,0,\ldots,0)^T$.  So we want $T e_1 = b$ where $Ab = Bb = 0$ and $b \ne 0$.  That's the first column of $T$.  For the other columns, take any basis of ${\mathbb K}^n$ whose first element is $b$.

Comment: Thank you Robert. Yes I mean the dimension of the intersection of the null spaces of $A$ and $B$ is $\geq $ 1.